# Add more markers with different location in Google maps in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, location, marker

How can I add more locations to my google maps and have them  get the same  marker icon to each different location?

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
  function initMap() {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(50.0875726, 14.4189987);

    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var mapOptions = {
      center: location,
      zoom: 16,
      panControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    var markerImage = "marker.png";

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      icon: markerImage
    });

    var contentString =
      '<div class="info-window">' +
      "<h3>Info Window Content</h3>" +
      '<div class="info-content">' +
      "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>";

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
    });

    marker.addListener("click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    var styles = [
      {
        featureType: "landscape",
        stylers: [{ saturation: -100 }, { lightness: 65 }, { visibility: "on" }]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        stylers: [
          { saturation: -100 },
          { lightness: 51 },
          { visibility: "simplified" }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.highway",
        stylers: [{ saturation: -100 }, { visibility: "simplified" }]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.arterial",
        stylers: [{ saturation: -100 }, { lightness: 30 }, { visibility: "on" }]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.local",
        stylers: [{ saturation: -100 }, { lightness: 40 }, { visibility: "on" }]
      },
      {
        featureType: "transit",
        stylers: [{ saturation: -100 }, { visibility: "simplified" }]
      },
      {
        featureType: "administrative.province",
        stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
      },
      {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
          { visibility: "on" },
          { lightness: -25 },
          { saturation: -100 }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{ hue: "#ffff00" }, { lightness: -25 }, { saturation: -97 }]
      }
    ];

    map.set("styles", styles);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
});
```

I will be very grateful for your help, I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of objects that contains the coordinates (lat and long). Use `forEach` to loop thru the array and make a marker.

```
var listOfLocations = [
  {lat: 18.906286,lng: 19.102439},      //Somewhere in Africa
  {lat: 8.331083,lng: 105.549002},      //Somewhere near Vietnam
  {lat: -27.440040,lng: 135.067341},    //Somewhere in Australia
  {lat: -14.338904,lng: -51.507365},    //Somewhere in Brazil
];

listOfLocations.forEach(function(o) {               //Loop thru the array
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({             //Make the marker and add to the map
    position: o,
    map: map,
    icon: markerImage                               //Set image
  });
})
```

**Note:** No need to make `new google.maps.LatLng` object as per [Google Map Marker Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Comment: I am sorry to be such a bother,can you show me how the code will look like as a whole, I am new and can't fully comprehend how to fix it.

Comment: You can copy the code and paste it after your map. The locations are scattered across the world. You might need to zoom out to see all the markers. @skan

Comment: Sorry again but where do i put the new locations that  you so generously  provided I tried but the map did not show up.

Comment: Does the map show without the new code?

Comment: yes it does   and it shows  this location "" var location = new google.maps.LatLng(50.0875726, 14.4189987);"" with it's marker.

Comment: You can paste the code after `marker.addListener("click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });`

Comment: My friend you are awesome thanks a lot. if it does not bother you can you tell me how can i get the new locations to have the same Marker icon like the previous one ?

Comment: You mean, how to get new lat and long near the original marker?

Comment: No i am using a image  as the icon of the marker instead of the default one,Do you know how can I have all the locations use the same image ?

Comment: Ohhh... I updated the code. Please check

Comment: you are a hero thanks a lot I am so grateful to you.it really outstanding how can you understand  coding so well.
Thanks a lot.